# How to transfer particular value in Wordpress on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am new to Wordpress and stuck to one problem, I have many buttons and if user click on that particular button then form popup and also the pdf link transfer and on submit button click which present on popup form that pdf link get trigger.

Comment: Please provide some code, like what have you tried?

Comment: I'm totally don't understand your question. And I know something or two about wordpress. If your question is not specific for wordpress (like "how to trigger click on link" (your pdf link)), let us know. If it doe's, explain how..

Comment: @MoshFeu I will give you some example so you can get clear vision about my question, Suppose there are three buttons Google, Facebook, Twitter. 1) I am click on Google button then pop up form open then user fill the form and when user submit the form google.pdf link gets trigger. 2) I am click on Facebook button then pop up form open then user fill the form and when user submit the form Facebook.pdf link gets trigger.

Comment: `gets trigger` means trigger click, so the user will be transfer to the pdf url?

Comment: yes but the pdf url is diffrent for diffrent buttons.